# Transactional Replication between SQL Server 2017(Publisher+Distributor) and SQL Server 2019(Subscriber)

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2017, transactional-replication, sql-server-2019

So here's the replication scenario that we need to set up.
At organization A, We have SQL Server 2017 which is both the publisher and a distributor.
At organization B, on a remote server, we have a SQL Server 2019 which needs to be a subscriber.

When we are trying to set up the transactional replication between these two servers and while adding the subscriber, it throws this error: The selected Subscriber does not satisfy the minimum version compatibility level of the selected publication.

According to the [Replication compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15), it looks like it is supposed to be working fine, but then we cant seem to understand why this is still failing.
[image]

[Similar Stack Question that I have referred to](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160400/replication-between-two-different-sql-server-versions)

[Another link that talks about Microsoft Replication between two different versions of SQL servers](https://repltalk.com/2016/08/12/suppported-sql-server-versions-in-replication-topology/)

Answer (score 1):

What are the [Compatibility Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15) for the replicated database of your SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019 instances? Is the 2017 instance set to the default level of 140 and 2019 instance set to the default level of 150? This is a guess but if the 2017 server is set to an old enough level, perhaps that's the issue?

You can verify the Compatibility Levels of the database here: [View or Change the Compatibility Level of a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Or using this query from the docs linked above:

```
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'YourReplicatedDatabaseName';
```